# Textmate Regex Simple Find/Replace

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

I am trying to do a simple find and replace. I have:

```
  <?php $url = 'http://www.mywebsite.net/this-is-a-page.php'; ?>
```

as a variable on each page and I'm replacing it with:

```
  <?php $url = curPageURL(); ?>
```

I had my find set up like this:

```
   <?php $url =( .*); ?>
```

but that's clearly incorrect because it doesn't return any results when I hit find. Any help would be super appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape some characters.

Try this  `<\?php \$url =( .*); \?>`

- `?` denotes 0 or 1 of the previous character.
- `$` denotes end of line.

Escaping them changes them to literal matches.

Answer (score 0):

You have your capture group on the bit you want to replace instead of the bits you want to keep. I think you need something like this:

```
(<\?php \$url =)[^\?]+(\?>)
```

then replace it with

```
\1 curPageURL();\2
```

Not sure if TextMate uses `\1` for reference or `$1`

Comment: Textmate uses $1 for reference.